# How can I fix this error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a program that create and read .txt files, this function `OpenFile` should open a selected file but this error appeared. What can I do to the program have authorized access?

```
void OpenFile()
{

    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    string directory = info.DirectoryName;

    StreamReader str = new StreamReader(directory);

    string read = str.ReadLine();

    LoadScreenWithText(read);
}
```

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\NotePad' was denied'

Comment: Well, the [documentation on `StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_) says the argument of the constructor you use has to be a path to a file but you're giving it a path to a directory. Maybe that's the problem? Would would you image would happen when you read a line from a directory anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming that you are getting and absolute file path in  this property "openFileDialog1.FileName"

Try running you program using "Run as administrator" by right clicking on EXE .If you are debugging it with visual studio run VS as an administrator .

[image]

Note :Good practice is to always check that whether the file exist or not before further proceeding

Use:

```
  openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
 if(File.Exists(openFileDialog1.FileName){
   //Your rest of the code 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've tried it sometimes but it doesn't work. I have to find a way to do it works, it's complicated.